# Как в JS ES6 классах унаследовать свойство родителя, чтобы дальше передать его для вычисления

Tags: javascript, классы, ecmascript-6

Есть input type="date" при его изменении вычисляется значение, как это значение передать дочернему классу. Читал справку, там передаются параметры, а если я вычисляю свойство, то как мне его потом получить в дочернем классе, чтобы дальше производить с ним следующие операции

```html
<body>
  <div class="input">
    <input type='date' />
  </div>
  <div class="containerForLastUpdateRecordAndPeriodItems"></div>

  <script>
    class dateInput {
      constructor() {
        this.input = document.querySelector("input[type='date']");
        this.input.onchange = this.onChange;
      }            

      onChange(event) {
        this.inputValue = event.target.value;
        console.log('В датаИмпуте', this.inputValue)        
        this.updateTime = new Date();
        console.log('В updateTime', this.updateTime)
        return this.inputValue;
      }
    }

    class dateRange extends dateInput {
     constructor() {
       super();       
       this.container = document.querySelector('.containerForLastUpdateRecordAndPeriodItems');
     }
     
     onChange() {       
       console.log(this.inputValue);
       this.createPeriod(this.inputValue);
     }

     createPeriod(date) {
       let newDate = date;
       console.log(newDate);
       newDate.year = newDate.year + 1;
       return {
         start: date,
         end: newDate
       }
     }
    }

    const range = new dateRange();

  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае вы полностью перезаписываете метод, не используя метод родительского класса.

Вам нужно воспользоваться зарезервированным словом `super`

```js
class dateInput {
  constructor() {
    this.input = document.querySelector("input[type='date']");
    this.input.onchange = this.onChange.bind(this); // иначе потереяте контекст
  }            

  onChange(event) {
    this.inputValue = new Date(event.target.value);
    console.log('В датаИнпуте', this.inputValue)        
    this.updateTime = new Date();
    console.log('В updateTime', this.updateTime)
  }
}

class dateRange extends dateInput {
  constructor() {
    super();       
    this.container = document.querySelector('.containerForLastUpdateRecordAndPeriodItems');
  }
     
  onChange(event) {
     super.onChange(event); // вызываем метод родительского класса
     console.log(this.inputValue); // this.inputValue уже доступен
     const result = this.createPeriod();
     console.log(result);
  }

  createPeriod() {
    let newDate = this.inputValue; // не обязательно передавать параметры
    newDate.setYear(+newDate.getFullYear() + 1); // это делается так
    console.log(newDate);
    return {
      start: this.inputValue,
      end: newDate
    }
  }
}

const range = new dateRange();
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="input">
    <input type='date' />
  </div>
  <div class="containerForLastUpdateRecordAndPeriodItems"></div>
</body>
```